# How to ensure atomic transactions for update operations to different NoSQL data tables?

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

[image: Update operation]

Problem is like the picture, say my application needs to write to two different DynamoDB tables, how I ensure that I don't have data inconsistency when one of my operation fails?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [transaction library](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-transaction-library/) for DynamoDB

However, note that this is quite expensive (7x normal cost, I believe), and in general it is better to try and design your database in a way that would not require such transactions.

Alternatively, you can have an AWS lambda listening to one table, and triggering update to a second table when update happens on first one.

Finally, if you need such relations, consider using RDS, instead of DynamoDB